# Remove quotation marks from an object

Tags: ruby, string, eval

I want to call `User.first`, but I get it like `"User.first"`. How can I strip the quotation marks so I can call `User`? Using a regex like this: `gsub!(/\A"|"\Z/, "")` returns `nil` instead of the expression.

Comment: The regular expression works for me. Are the quotes really part of the string?

Comment: @Meier, the above doesn't work, because gsub only evaluates what is inside the string. That is why it returns nil. If I do "'User.first'"gsub!(/\A'|'\Z/, "") I'll get back "User.first" because the single quotes are part of the string, but the double quotes are not. kevinthompsons answer is correct.

Comment: So the quotes are not part of the string. The quotes are just syntax needed by the ruby interpreter to know that the inside is a string. The quotes do not exist at runtime, that is why try to remove them with gsub fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I would say that it's dangerous to do this based on where your input is coming from, but if you absolutely need to run arbitrary ruby code contained in a string, you would use `eval`:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-eval

Again, I would avoid evaluating strings if at all possible.